# Tools for Server application testing

Tags: java, test-design, tools

I'm currently working (almost finishing) a Java project that consists on a server application and some client applications on the same network, that will communicate with the server only to request informations. So what tools are suggested to use for this kind of testing?

Comment: Nathan - could you expand a little on what sort of testing you would like to find tools for? Performance testing, functionality, automating regression checks? If you can name a few categories of the sorts of tests you think you might want to run, it may help in getting better recommendations.

Comment: I'm primary looking for performance and functionality tests

Comment: I'm voting to close as the question is overly broad. It's not clear what protocol is used for communicating with server applications, so no specific tool can be proposed.  Please be specific.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TestNG is appropriated for functional testing (and unit test, by the way). For performance test, Grinder is probably a good choice:

http://grinder.sourceforge.net/

The Eclipse plugin:

http://code.google.com/p/grinderstone/

Answer (score 7):

Try [Jmeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/index.html) to test performance of your app.

Comment: good call - again, I think you can get a plugin for eclipse.

Answer (score 7):

If you are looking for automated UI testing using java then [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) is worth having a look at....

Answer (score 6):

[SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) is a nice tool to test (not only SOAP!) webservices, define several types of assertions on the responses, build functional tests and also derive load tests from functional tests.

As a (super nice) plus, mostly everything in SoapUI can be scripted with Groovy, which allows for even more flexible testing, and finally, there is also a Maven-Plugin which lets you integrate all your tests easily in a continuous integration/testing/deployment scenario.

Answer (score 5):

JUnit is also an option if you want to test functionality.

Comment: agreed. You can JUnit for unit & integration tests. Get a plugin for eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

The combo of JUnit and Selenium would handle most if not all of your needs, especially if your app is browser based.

Comment: Spot on. be careful with record/playback automation tho - ensure your UI is stable (hopefully it is if you're nearing the end of the project

Answer (score 1):

As you wrote in the comment your are mainly looking for performance testing and functional testing,

For performance testing I would recommend you user [Jmeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/). It is a java based tool so it should work really fine and for web applications I would suggest you record your test scripts using Blazemeter (an extension of Google Chrome). Here is a tutorial to help you with it - http://testacy.co.in/performance-testing-jmeter/

For functional testing I would suggest you to use Selenium Webdriver and if you are familiar with the TestNG framework of Webdriver that would be more preferable. Since Selenium is open source project you will get a lot of help from countless blogs and forums dedicated to it.

Regards,

Milin Patel

Software Tester

http://testacy.co.in

Answer (score 0):

Though JUnit helps in writing unit test cases for java code, it will not be able to help you to speed up the testing process with increasing numbers of test cases to be executed and more data to be processed.

Jthunder is a core automation framework which helps in enabling multi-threaded processing of any JUnit tests/Java code.

Have a look at the Jthunder framework documentation.

[Jthunder official blog](https://code.google.com/p/jthunder/)

Comment: Java guru, if you have any affiliation with the Jthunder project, you should mention this: otherwise your post is little more than advertisement.

Answer (score 0):

As you are looking for tools for functional testing of your application, I can recommend [Ranorex](http://www.ranorex.com). It is a powerful tool for testing the UI of your application automatically.  At the end of every test run an XML based report is generated, containing screenshots if anything went wrong.

Comment: That's good for a start! Could you link some reference material along with this?