# Tools for Python software testing

Tags: automated-testing, tools, python

> Similar to [Tools for Server application testing](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/48/tools-for-java-software-testing), I'm looking for Python-related testing tools/software (as Python is my most frequently-used language).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

While it's not updated as regularly as it once was, Grig Gheorgiu's [Python Testing Tools Taxonomy](http://packages.python.org/testing/) is considered by Pythonistas to be an excellent reference point for tools. It covers the following kinds of testing tools:

- Unit Testing Tools
- Mock Testing Tools
- Fuzz Testing Tools
- Web Testing Tools
- Acceptance/Business Logic Testing Tools
- GUI Testing Tools
- Source Code Checking Tools
- Code Coverage Tools
- Continuous Integration Tools
- Test Fixtures
- Miscellaneous Python Testing Tools

Answer (score 5):

I had only one experience of automation testing for Qt apps on Linux. The tool I used is [Squish](http://www.froglogic.com/index.php), and it supports Java, Web and Mobile testing as well. The test scripts are written in python. Just FYI. It's a commercial product, you need to buy the license.

Comment: You can write Squish test scripts in a couple of other languages as well, but Python is the default, possibly because it was the language used to code Squish.
Oh, and you can get Windows and Mac versions of Squish, too.

Answer (score 4):

**Mechanize** is quite powerful request-based tool to test web apps. http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/

Comment: Mechanize is included in twill http://twill.idyll.org/

Answer (score 2):

Here's also a [good list of Python test tools](https://github.com/atinfo/awesome-test-automation/blob/master/python-test-automation.md) from automated-testing.info community.